# How do Sri Vaishnavas interpret this Sutra of the Apastamba Dharma Sutras?

Tags: sri-vaishnava, dharma-shastras, vishishtadvaita

> **Apastamba Dharma Sutras (2.9.21.13)** - Abandoning truth and falsehood, pleasure and pain, the Vedas, this
>   world and the next, he shall seek the ātman.

My question is about the abandoning the "truth and falsehood," and "Vedas" part. What do Sri Vaishnava Acharyas say about this verse?

There are 3 Sutras in this section that appear to enjoin things that the Vedic scholars of the Sri Vaishnava sampradaya disagree with.

These sutras are:

> *sarvataḥ parimokṣam eke || 12 ||*
>
> 12. Some declare that he shall go naked.
>
> *satya anṛte sukha duḥkhe vedān imaṃ lokam amuṃ ca parityajya-ātmānam
>   anvicchet || 13 ||*
>
> 13. Abandoning truth and falsehood, pleasure and pain, the Vedas, this world and the next, he shall seek the ātman.
>
> *buddhe kṣema prāpaṇam* || 14 ||
>
> 14. [Some say that] he obtains Liberation if he [theoretically] knows [the ātman].

These 3 injunctions are rejected by Sri Vaishnava Sannyasis, but they are accepted by Advaitins who follow Shankaracharya.

However, the next Sutra of Apastamba says this:

> *tat-śāstrair vipratiṣiddham* || 15 ||
>
> 15. [But] that [opinion] is opposed to the Shastras.

And the next one:

> *buddhe cet kṣema prāpaṇam iha-eva na duḥkham upalabheta* || 16 ||
>
> 16. [For] if liberation were obtained by the [theoretical] knowledge of the
>       ātman alone, then one ought not to experience suffering even in this
>       [world].

I just want to confirm that the 3 preceding sutras are rejected by sutra 15.

Comment: 15 refers only to 14 as theoretically knowing the Atman alone is not realisation as per sastras is being mentioned in 16.At least 15 is related only to 14 and it does not depend on interpretation of any commentator of any sect.

Comment: @Pratimaputra Actually I think sutra 15 rejects sutras 12, 13, and 14.

Comment: since you're asking for interpretation , can you post original sanskrit verses ?

Comment: @ram I have updated the OP with original sanskrit verses. Please check.

Comment: Voting to close as unclear. Title says 'How do Sri Vaishnavas interpret this Sutra of the Apastamba Dharma Sutras?' and body says 'These 3 injunctions are rejected by Sri Vaishnava Sannyasis' - what exactly is your question?

Comment: @sv, isn't it clear from his last line asking for confirmation i.e. OP has both a question and a pre-conceived notion regarding the answer. you may have asked such questions in the past as well.